# How to rank values from asc/descending?

Tags: business-intelligence, spotfire

Struggling to find rank values from highest to lowest, please see attached example of what I'm trying to achieve.

My current custom expression is:

`Sum([ViolationAmt])`

I have tried this:

```
Sum([ViolationAmt]) over Rank([ViolationAmt])
```

I've played around with the rank expressions however unable to implement...would be very grateful for some help.

[Spotfire Rank Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJjYa.png)

[image]

Comment: you are being downvoted because you haven't shown what you have tried so far. please edit your question to include this info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I need to make a lot of assumptions here because I don't know anything about your data set or really what your end goal is, so please comment back and/or provide more info in your question if I am off base.

the first assumption is that each row in your dataset represents one, for simplicity, `[AccountID]` with a `[ViolationAmt]`. I'm also guessing you want to show the top N accounts with the highest violations in a table, since that's what you've shown here.

so it sounds like you are going to need two calculated columns: one for getting the total `[ViolationAmt]` per account, and then another to rank them.

for the first, create a column called `[TotalViolationAmt]` or somesuch and use:

```
Sum([ViolationAmt]) OVER ([AccountID])
```

for the second:

```
Rank([TotalViolationAmt])
```

it will be useful to read the [documentation on ranking functions](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire/7.0.1/doc/html/ncfe/ncfe_ranking_functions.htm) if you haven't already.

you could probably combine these two into a single column with something like:

```
Rank(Sum([ViolationAmt]) OVER ([AccountID]))
```

but I haven't tested this at all. again, if you put in a bit more detail about what you're trying to accomplish it will help you get a better, more detailed answer :)